# MouseFlow manual trigger

Tags: jquery

I want to create a manual feedback campaign with mouseflow, and I want to select clients with at least one item on their cart.

```
//Mouseflow
if ($('span .count') >= 1){
  window._mfq = window._mfq || [];
  window._mfq.push(['activateFeedback', 'id']);
}
```

there is my JQuery code, the value is stored in a span with a class = count.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: The id part is replaced with my feedback id provided by MouseFlow and im testing this with a copy of a Shopify theme.

Comment: the question is why it doesn't work, sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without seeing your live code. But shouldn't you be using '.length'?

Try to test if this works:

```
//Mouseflow
if ($('span .count').length >= 1){
  window._mfq = window._mfq || [];
  window._mfq.push(['activateFeedback', 'id']);
}
```

Comment: try it and still doesn't work, what i want is I have a cart on the webpage and when you have an item on the cart and you return to the page a poll will appear. This is the code that i'm selecting https://ibb.co/ddOSqy

Comment: I've tested, and my answer works with the code in your example. Try testing yourself, maybe using 'console.log' inside the statement. Looks like the problem is elsewhere in the code - maybe there's a timing issue, or maybe the Mouseflow code isn't set up to trigger. Without access to a live page, it's impossible to say for sure.